Codeigniter4 Grocery Crud custom model
I want to implement a custom model from Grocery Crud but I see that CI4 does not have get_instance anymore. As per the example I need to do:
<?php
//CustomersModel.php

use GroceryCrud\Core\Model;
use GroceryCrud\Core\Model\ModelFieldType;

class CustomersModel extends Model {

    protected $ci;
    protected $db;

    function __construct($databaseConfig) {
        $this->setDatabaseConnection($databaseConfig);

        $this->ci = & get_instance();
        $this->db = $this->ci->db;
    }

    public function getFieldTypes($tableName)
    {
     ...

The question is, how may I get a CI4 context as this example is for CI3?
Example website: https://www.grocerycrud.com/docs/custom-model

This should be relevant for you explain $CI =& get_instance();

get_instance() was used in CI 3.x. CodeIgniter 4 also provides the functionality to create and share new class instances. It is implemented as the Config\Services class
